# Displaying a hint mode in a hangman game js UPDATE

Tags: javascript

Now  after implementing the hint mode, the guessing part does not work, meaning I cannot guess a letter. This means that the lives do not reduce and no one can win or lose the game. The hint mode works perfectly.

```
      function setup() {
      alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      lives = 8;
      var words = ["ayeupmeducks", "pieceofcake", 
     "bullinachinashop", "hangfire","greeneyedmonster", 
     "hairraising","bringhomethebacon","adiamondintherough","onceinabluemoon",
     "afootinthedoor","bitethebullet"];

    messages = {
        win: 'Congratulations you have won the game of Hangman!',
        lose: 'You have been Hanged !!',
        guessed: ' already guessed, please try again...',
        validLetter: 'Please enter a letter from A-Z'
    };

      var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
      var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");
      getHint.onclick = function() {
      hints = ["Stoke Greeting","Saying Something is Easy",
               "Very Clumsy","delaying something for a minute", 
               "When you are jealous of something",
              "Something is frightening", "Earn Money", 
              "Rough Exterior however has some potential", 
              "When something rarely happens", 
              "When you have succeeded/ getting yourself known by a company",
              "accepting something , when you do not want to"];

    var hintIndex = words
    showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: - " +  hints [idx];};

    gussedLetter = matchedLetter = '';
    numberofMatchedLetters = 0;
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var currentWord = words[idx];
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    guessInput = document.getElementById("letter");
    message.innerHTML = 'You have ' + lives + ' lives remaining';
    output.innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("letter").value = '';

    guessButton = document.getElementById("guess");
    guessInput.style.display = 'inline';
    guessButton.style.display = 'inline';

    letters = document.getElementById("letters");
    letters.innerHTML = '<li class="current-word">Current word:</li>';
    var letter, i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
        letter = '<li class="letter letter' + currentWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + '">' + currentWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + '</li>';
        letters.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', letter);
    }
}

function gameOver(win) {
    if (win) {
        output.innerHTML = messages.win;
        output.classList.add('win');
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = messages.lose;
        output.classList.add('error');
    } 
    guessInput.style.display = guessButton.style.display = 'none';
    guessInput.value = '';
}

window.onload = setup();

document.getElementById("restart").onclick = setup;

guessInput.onclick = function () {
    this.value = '';
};
document.getElementById('hangman').onsubmit = function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    output.innerHTML = '';
    output.classList.remove('error', 'warning');
    guess = guessInput.value;

    if (guess) {
        if (alphabet.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
            if ((matchedLetter && matchedLetter.indexOf(guess) > -1) || (gussedLetter && gussedLetter.indexOf(guess) > -1)) {
                output.innerHTML = '"' + guess.toUpperCase() + '"' + messages.guessed;
                output.classList.add("warning");
            }
            else if (currentWord.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
                var lettersToShow;
                lettersToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".letter" + guess.toUpperCase());

                for (var i = 0; i < lettersToShow.length; i++) {
                     lettersToShow[i].classList.add("correct");
                }

                for (var j = 0; j < currentWord.length; j++) {
                    if (currentWord.charAt(j) === guess) {
                        numberofMatchedLetters += 1;
                    }
                }

                matchedLetter += guess;
                if (numberofMatchedLetters === currentWord.length) {
                    gameOver(true);
                }
            }
            else {
                gussedLetter += guess;
                lives--;
                message.innerHTML = 'You have ' + lives + ' lives remaining';
                if (lives === 0) gameOver();
            }
        }
        else {
            output.classList.add('error');
            output.innerHTML = messages.validLetter;
        }
    }
    else {
        output.classList.add('error');
        output.innerHTML = messages.validLetter;
    }
    return false;
};
```

The variables as far as I can see are still the same, so I do not get why an error occurs?.

Comment: `currentWord` is not a numbered index. It's a value from the `words` array. Perhaps you wanted to get the index of that word from the `words` array. Also, you need to flatten the hints array.
`var hintIndex = currentWord` is not a number as such `hints[hitIndex]` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the array in array problem, you also need to store the index itself and use that instead of the word.

Also you have typo: `hint.onclick` should be `getHint.onclick`.

```js
var words = ["ayeupmeducks", "pieceofcake", "bullinachinashop", "hangfire","greeneyedmonster",       "hairraising","bringhomethebacon","adiamondintherough","onceinabluemoon","afootinthedoor","bitethebullet"];

var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
var currentWord = words[idx];

var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");

getHint.onclick = function() {
    var hints = ["Stoke Greeting","Saying Something is Easy", "Very Clumsy","delaying something for a minute", "When you are jealous of something","Something is frightening", "Earn Money", "Rough Exterior however has some potential", "When something rarely happens", "When you have succeeded/ getting yourself known by a company","accepting something , when you do not want to"];
    showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: - " +  hints [idx];
};
```

```html
<button id="hint" name="hint" type="button">Hint</button>
<p id="clue">Clue: </p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However now that I have implemented this my code is not working when it comes to outputting the current word

Comment: Well the word is still in `currentWord` variable, just like it was before. Feel free to update your question with more code that fails or open a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array containing an array :

```
   hints = [
        ["Stoke Greeting","Saying Something is Easy", "Very Clumsy","delaying something for a minute", "When you are jealous of something","Something is frightening", "Earn Money", "Rough Exterior however has some potential", "When something rarely happens", "When you have succeeded/ getting yourself known by a company","accepting something , when you do not want to"]  
         ];
```

Change it to a simple array :

```
hints = ["Stoke Greeting","Saying Something is Easy", "Very Clumsy","delaying something for a minute", "When you are jealous of something","Something is frightening", "Earn Money", "Rough Exterior however has some potential", "When something rarely happens", "When you have succeeded/ getting yourself known by a company","accepting something , when you do not want to"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it- Thank you for all your help :) 
I changed it current word from being a variable and now it works